# Agrupar resultado por columna en respuesta de AJAX PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo la siguiente Tabla en la base de datos, quiero recuperarla para generar un reporte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estoy recuperando con la siguiente sentencia función en php:

```
#BUSCAR CAJA Y BOLSAS
     public function todoReporteModel($datos, $tabla){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar() -> prepare("SELECT bolsa, caja FROM $tabla WHERE lote=:lotes");
        $stmt -> bindParam(":lotes", $datos["loteAll"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        return  $stmt -> fetchAll();
        $stmt->close();
   }
```

La respuesta que obtengo es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi consulta es:

¿Como puedo ordenar cuando recibo la respuesta, de tal manera que se agrupen los valores de las bolsas en cada caja, en funcion del numero de cajas que haya? Por ejemplo:

```
caja1=[1,2,3,40];
caja2=[89,78,968,125,963];
caja0=[10];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede intentar lo siguiente para obtener `arrays` donde la clave será la primera columna `PDO::FETCH_GROUP` de su `SELECT` el resto serán valores como normalmente se usa asociativo `FETCH_ASSOC.`

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT caja , bolsa FROM cajas WHERE lote= :lotes")){
    $stmt->bindParam(":lotes", $datos["loteAll"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $total = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($total[0]); // obtenemos los de la caja 0
}
```

Otra forma sería crear un array e ir añadiendo los elementos según su clave

```
$data = array();
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT caja , bolsa FROM cajas WHERE lote= :lotes")){
    $stmt->bindParam(":lotes", $datos["loteAll"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )){ 
         //Insertamos nuevo array en el Indice según la columna caja
         $data[$row['caja']][] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

En su método `Ajax` en el `success` o `done` puede recuperar los datos de la siguiente forma haciendo uso de [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/entries)

```
$.ajax({

})
.done(function(respuesta ) {
    let result = Object.entries(respuesta );
    console.log(result[1]);//caja1
    console.log(result[0][1]);//Elementos de caja 1
})
```

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias, una consulta en el AJAX, lo estoy recibiendo con esto: 
`success: function(respuesta) {
         console.log("Tamaño: ", respuesta.length);
          console.log("Respuesta: ", respuesta);
       }`
Como puedo saber el tamaño del total enviado, que en este caso seria 4 (porque son 4 cajas segun el ejemplo), gracias (Ya que el `respuesta.length`no me sirve)

Comment: @Baker1562 cuál de las dos opciones en mi respuesta eligió , y como está haciendo el retorno de los datos  ?

Comment: La primera me parecio mas sencilla y me decidi por esa, gracias.

Comment: intente con `Object.keys(respuesta).length` para obtener la cantidad de elementos. Saludos espero le ayude.

Comment: @Baker1562 he añadido para recoger los datos desde ajax, igual se está saliendo del foco principal la pregunta. y cuando pasa esto, los comentarios se hacen extensos y no es lo correcto.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que necesitas es sumar el total que tiene cada bolsa por su número de caja, puedes aplicar un `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT SUM(bolsa), caja FROM info GROUP BY caja;
```

Lo que hace es ir sumando lo que tiene cada bolsa agrupado por su ID de caja.

Aquí esta un ejemplo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37f112/7